# Persian rug recursion

Tags: java, swing, recursion

I'm learning recursion I found some cool stuff like this link that implements recursion in order to do a Persian carpet. I want to implement this code in Java

```
float a = 1.0;
int left = 0;
int right = 340;
int top = 0;
int bot = 340;
int r,g,b;
color firstColor;
color backC;

//color backC = color(35,95,28);
 
void setup()
{
  //size(700, 700);
  size(341, 341);
  r = floor(random(1,255));
  g = floor(random(1,255));
  b = floor(random(1,255));
  firstColor = color(g);    
  backC = color(r,g,b);
  background(backC);
  stroke(firstColor); 
  line(left,top,right,top);
  line(left,bot,right,bot);
  line(left,top,left,bot);
  line(right,top,right,bot);
  a = random(1,6);
  chooseColor(left, right, top, bot, a);
}
 
void draw()
{}
 
void chooseColor(int left, int right, int top, int bot, float a)
{
  int midcol, midrow;
  color col;
   
  if (left < (right-1))
     {
       col = floor((get(left,top) + get(right,top) + get(left,bot) + get(right,bot))/a);
       midcol = (left + right) / 2;
       midrow = (top + bot) / 2;
       stroke(col);
       line(left+1, midrow, right-1, midrow);
       line(midcol, top+1, midcol, bot-1);
       chooseColor(left, midcol, top, midrow, a);
       chooseColor(midcol, right, top, midrow, a);
       chooseColor(left, midcol, midrow, bot, a);
       chooseColor(midcol, right, midrow, bot, a);
     }
}
 
void keyPressed()
{
     setup();
}
```

I'm using a JFrame for my window and a JPanel for the drawing but the code is really different from java, can someone give me an advice of where to start? I know the code uses colors, but I'm trying to make the rug only in black, so afterwards I can implement some color.

Comment: Quick note: The actual algorithm used by the weavers is probably iterative, not recursive... humans don't manage deep stacks very well.

Comment: Is the code in your question [Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info) ?